# Editing record does not bring about any result in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mdf

I have following code to fill my dataset (ASP.Net).

```
Dim conStr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim sqlQry As String = "SELECT * FROM tblTest"
Dim dAdt As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQry, conStr)
Dim dSet As New DataSet()
```

dAdt.Fill(dSet, "tblTest")

Then I am using following to edit my record

```
Dim dRow As DataRow
    dRow = dSet.Tables("tblTest").Rows(1)
    dRow.BeginEdit()
    dRow.Item("Name") = txtName.Text
    dRow.EndEdit()
    dSet.Tables("tblTest").AcceptChanges()
```

it does not generate any error but does not edit the record too.  Same is happening when I try to delete record using delete command.  Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Does not edit the record in the DataSet or in the Database? It will not update the Database if that is what you are wanting

Comment: I need to change record in the Database........ Could you kindly help me?

Comment: You need to look into updating the database with ado.net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302325.aspx

Comment: Does it really relate to my questions????????

Comment: Yes and no. Yes in the way that you need to look into how to update a database using ado.net, and NO in the way that your code will not update the database the way you are doing it.

Comment: Could you kindly modify my code to make it so?  I shall be really thankful for you as this is really confusing for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3215/discussion-between-furqan-sehgal-and-tim-b-james)

Comment: It is not really for us to give you the answer to something which you have not even attempted to answer for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call "update" before AcceptChanges.

Something like:

```
dset.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the BeginEdit() and AcceptChanges() methods, like this:

```
drRow.BeginEdit()
drRow("Name") = txtName.Text

dsSet.Tables("tblTest").AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: Do you mean just remove drRow.EndEdit()?  I tried it did not work.  Result is the same, unchanged data.

Comment: Are you sure that drRow.Item("Name") works? Shouldn't it be drRow("Name") = txtName.Text?

Comment: Well I changed it but did not make any changes to my database